# Jquery / Javascript sqlite: error while fetching data

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite

I found this [tutorial](https://tejasrpatel.wordpress.com/2011/12/29/create-sqlite-off-line-database-and-insertupdatedeletedrop-operations-in-sqlite-using-jquery-html5-inputs/) by googling.

Creating table is working, but while fetching data its showing an alert; says undefined. after alert its giving me result also. below is the function, kindly help

```
var db = openDatabase("mydb", "1.0", "mydb", 200000);
`var dataset;`
var createtablelogin = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS login (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,onlineid INTEGER, name TEXT, email TEXT,password TEXT,mobile INTEGER,employeeid INTEGER)";

var statementchecklogin="SELECT * FROM login";

function initDatabase(){
    try {
        if (!window.openDatabase)
        {
            alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
        } else {
            createtable(createtablelogin);
        }
    }catch (e){
        if (e == 2) {
            alert("Invalid database version.");
        } else {
            alert("Unknown error " + e + ".");
        }
        return;
    }
}

function itsokay(){
    console.log('DB initiated');
}

function onError(tx, error){
    alert(error.message);
}

function createtable(stmt){
    db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(stmt, [],itsokay,onError);});
}

function showRecords(stmt,arrgs){
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql(stmt, arrgs, function (tx, result) {
            dataset = result.rows;
        });
    });
}

$(document).ready(function){
  initdatabase();
  showRecords(statementchecklogin,[]);
});
```

What wrong am I doing?

***SLOVED***
**`//var dataset; --> this was the bug` 
whenever dataset was called it was accessing this variable. just removed it.**

Comment: is this your `OnError()` function that's firing?

Comment: How did you fill the database?

Comment: @SylviaStuurman i did not fill anything, its a login system and only one row will be there in this particular table. it needs to be checked everytime.

Comment: @wahwahwah did not get any error yet, not sure about that. only two function i wrote, 2nd one started troubling me.

Comment: @ManjunathHegde - what line of code is throwing the alert message? try trouble shooting it by checking the console (chrome - right click > inspect element > console)  if you are unsure.

Comment: @wahwahwah i am doing that, its not throwing any error in console log. just an alert. if i don't call showRecords, there is no error.